# Asp.net login and file upload question

Tags: asp.net, file, authentication, upload

Hey I just got a question, I haven't used asp.net before but am using c#/managed c++ but I was wondering how hard would it be to do the following.

1) Make a login system where users can register.
2) each user can upload 1 file each to a server.

And those files can only be accessed by that specific user by longing in.

I think its pretty basic so it shouldn't be to hard. Im guessing im going to need a database as well where both the username/passwords/files will be stored?

If anyone has any tutorials on this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a broad question and there are plenty of resources are out there on the web to help get started.

It's easy to set up a forms authentication system in ASP.Net 4 by just creating a new website as it automatically creates the login and registration pages for the website in a database using a "Membership Provider":

[Website User Authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/12/website-user-authentication-asp-net-web-applications.aspx)

You could create an "UploadFile" table in the database that has a reference to the file path and userName. When a user is authenticated you can get their User name from User.Identity.Name property and then check if they can upload a file.  You can use an ORM for easier database access and there are plenty to choose from such as Linq To SQL, Entity Framework, or NHibernate.

There are several tutorial videos on file uploads:

[Simple File Upload](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-simple-file-uploads-in-aspnet)

Of course there is much more to this but hopefully will give you some ideas on where to start learning.